# How to get plain string passwords from hash file?

Tags: windows, security, penetration-testing

I used samdump2 to extract hashes from SAM and SYSTEM files, here is what I got as result in a text file:

> *disabled* Administrator:500:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> *disabled* Guest:501:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> *disabled* :503:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> *disabled* :504:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> abc:1001:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> *disabled* :1009:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
>
> :1020:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::

I have the hashes but I have no idea how to extract plain text passwords from these hashes.
I have read some articles like this one: https://www.onlinehashcrack.com/how-to-extract-hashes-crack-windows-passwords.php

**Online Hash Crack** has this system to crack hashes online but somehow it didn't work, maybe I don't know the correct way to crack the hashes.
So how can I extract plain string passwords from these hashes?
btw the windows from which these SAM and SYSTEM files were taken has two local users.

Required files (just in case):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1txBB1OGcwPyLiKLXGdZPmSOJu0kZT0v-?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use JohnTheRipper for cracking the hashes. It will be much more stable and fast and JohnTheRipper optionally uses GPU power.

First of all, you should save the hash information in a text file. Then you can start the process you want with a command like the following.

john --format=NT --rules -w=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt hashfile.txt

If you want to get more detailed information, I recommend you to read the blog post below.

https://medium.com/secstudent/using-john-the-ripper-with-lm-hashes-f757bd4fb094

Last of thing, I am providing this information purely for educational purposes. If these hashes are not hashes of a system that belongs to you, you have definitely committed a legal crime and I recommend you to perform this operation only for educational purposes on your own systems.